# How to trace instance variable in Intellij

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I am new in intellij and like eclipse i want to trace instance variable.

In eclipse i was using ALT+CTRL+H but it is not working for instance variable in Intellij.

I tried ALT+CTRL+B but not working for IntelliJ

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "trace instance variable"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a table.
https://www.catalysts.cc/wissenswertes/intellij-idea-and-eclipse-shortcuts/

Alt + CTRL + B seems to jump to instance variable declarations in IDEA 139.1777. Same effect as holding CTRL and clicking the left mouse button.